# JSF Core Tag :setPropertyActionListener vs attribute vs param

Tags: jsf-2

What is the difference between `setPropertyActionListener` vs `attribute` vs `param`?

When would use the `setPropertyActionListener`?

Comment: Related: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html Note that since EL 2.2 you can pass arguments directly into action methods without the need for any of those tags.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**1. f:setPropertyActionListener:**

With this tag, you can directly set property in you backing bean. Example:

xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton action="page.xhtml" value="OK">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.name}" value="myname"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean{

    public String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

}
```

This will set `name` property of backing bean to value **myname**.

**2. f:param:**

This tag simple sets the request parameter. Example:

xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton action="page.xhtml">
    <f:param name="myparam" value="myvalue" />
</h:commandButton>
```

so you can get this parameter in backing bean:

```
FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("myparam")
```

**3. f:attribute:**

With this tag you can pass attribute so you can grab that attribute from action listener method of your backing bean.

xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton action="page.xhtml" actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"> 
    <f:attribute name="myattribute" value="myvalue" />
</h:commandButton>
```

so you can get this attribute from action listener method:

```
public void doSomething(ActionEvent event){
    String myattr = (String)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("myattribute");
}
```

You should use `f:setPropertyActionListener` whenever you want to set property of the backing bean. If you want to pass parameter to backing bean consider `f:param` and `f:attribute`. Also, it is important to know that with `f:param` you can just pass `String` values, and with `f:attribute` you can pass objects.

Comment: if i have a datatable and i put inside it 
`<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.selectedObject}" value="#{var}"/> `

i always get in my bean the `id` of the object not the whole object, can u explain me why?