# How can I change a bean property with a button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I'm trying to create a button that once clicked will change a property in a bean.

```
<h:commandButton type="button" action="#{loginBean.withdraw}" id="thousand" class="buttons"     style="top:180px;left:570px;">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{loginBean.withdrawAmount}" value="1000" />
</h:commandButton>
```

---

```
   public class LoginBean {

       int withdrawAmount;
```

This method only works when I omit the `type="button"` from the `commandButton`, but with the  `type="button"` it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

I need the `type="button"` to be there , is there any way to keep it and still make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your facelet snippet:

- There is **no such** attribute as `class` for `<h:commandButton>`. Possibly you meant `styleClass`.

As for the problem you have, you have to:

***Either*** provide a setter method for the `withdrawAmount` property

```
public void setWithdrawAmount(int withdrawAmount) {
    this.withdrawAmount = withdrawAmount;
}
```

and your facelet should look like:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" 
                 action="#{loginBean.withdraw}" 
                 id="thousand" 
                 styleClass="buttons" 
                 style="top:180px;left:570px;">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{loginBean.withdrawAmount}" 
                                 value="1000" />
</h:commandButton>
```

***Or***, you can get rid of the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` and add a statement the changes the value of the `withdrawAmount` as a first line of the `#{loginBean.withdraw}` method.

In this case your facelet snippet should look like:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" 
                 action="#{loginBean.withdraw}" 
                 id="thousand" 
                 styleClass="buttons" 
                 style="top:180px;left:570px;" />
```

and your `LoginBean#withdraw()` method should start with the statement, that changes the `withdrawAmount` value:

```
public String withdraw() {
    this.withdrawAmount = 1000;
    //the remaining logic.
}
```

Personally, I would prefer the first option.

---

More info:

- [< h:commandButton > tag reference](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_commandButton.html)
- [JSF Core Tag :setPropertyActionListener vs attribute vs param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474484/jsf-core-tag-setpropertyactionlistener-vs-attribute-vs-param)

Comment: `button` is [a valid option](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/). That's the variant used to trigger GET requests

Answer (score 2):

The `type` is the entire reason why you're having this issue. I'm posting this answer because the accepted answer doesn't explain *why* you're experiencing the issue.

`<h:commandButton/>` is designed to work in 3 modes:

- `submit`: This is the default mode that the button is set to. This mode sends an HTTP POST request to the server that triggers the JSF request processing lifecycle. It's only this mode that enables you to trigger backing bean methods(using the `action` or `actionListener` attributes).
- `button`: This mode triggers a GET request in the application. As GET requests go, this mode is mostly suited for navigation, i.e. requesting another view or page. In this mode, there's no easy/straightforward way to execute backing bean code, or trigger the JSF request processing lifecycle. This is your current issue
- `reset`: This mode simply resets the value of all input components within its enclosing `<h:form/>`

Reference:

- [JSF2 Command Button VDL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/)
- [JSF redirect via commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066416/jsf-redirect-via-commandbutton/18066576#18066576)
- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)